# Will my design work to program an ESP8285 IC?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, esp8266, wifi, esp32

Will this design work to program an ESP8285?

[image: Will this design works to program an ESL8285?]

I was trying to design an ESP8285 development board for the first time.

Before sending the design to manufacturing I would like to know whether or not the design can program the ESP8285.

Comment: General observation: circuits drawn this way (miniature circuit blocks) are much harder to follow than if they were all joined up properly with wires. Is there some overriding reason why some folk choose to draw diagrams like this? Is it a hobbyist thing or some great belief that net-name linkages are more reliable than virtual wires?

Comment: @Andyaka: I've seen it in the schematics for commercially produced modules.  I expect folks using those parts for hobby stuff copy the style